# How to detect changes in Google Spreadsheet? Java

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The spreadsheet holds events and my code has a linked list of these events organized by date.
However my code only reads the spreadsheet once.
So if the spreadsheet is every changed (added a row, deleted a row) my code doesn't know.
I'd like my spreadsheet to somehow notify my code that a change has been made.
Else I guess the other option is to check for any changes once a day with something like a while loop.
Thanks!

Comment: Look into the triggers for onEdit() and onChange()  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 events as mentioned in [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) on Google Developers Site, as follows

1. onOpen()
2. onEdit()
3. onChange()
4. onFormSubmit()

Update: These events are written in Google App Script and not in Java.